# MySQL service restart failed

Tags: mysql

```
[root@br52 ~]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting mysqld:
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please post the output of: `systemctl status mysql`?

Comment: service restarted


but issue in my database

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1286: Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' when using LOCK TABLES

Comment: From a quick Google search, have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303133/unknown-table-engine-innodb/10179592